# Redirect from managed bean event JSF

Tags: java, redirect, jsf-2

I have a JSF page containing a Pie Chart. The idea is that when the Sector of Pie Chart is clicked the application redirects to another page. I am facing Challenges Redirecting Because it is Only taking Full url to the page which is not Dynamic as it will change depending on the environment. My ItemSelect Method is :

```
public void itemSelect(ItemSelectEvent event) {

        try {

           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
             getExternalContext().redirect("http://localhost:8084/SIMBANK_BI/faces/OpenedAccountsProductTypeLevel.xhtml");

        } catch (IOException asd) {
            System.err.println(asd.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My JSF Page:

```
 <left>
             <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
            <p:pieChart id="custom" value="#{OpenedAccountsBranchLevelBean.pieModel}" legendPosition="w" showDataLabels="true"   
                style="width:500px;height:400px" sliceMargin="2">
                  <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{OpenedAccountsBranchLevelBean.itemSelect}" update="growl" />
            </p:pieChart>
        </left>
```

I have tried;

```
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                 getExternalContext().redirect("/faces/OpenedAccountsProductTypeLevel.xhtml");
```

I have also tried:

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                 getExternalContext().redirect("/OpenedAccountsProductTypeLevel.xhtml");
```

My Question is how Can I redirect without Having to place in the Entire URL??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    contextPath = origRequest.getContextPath();
try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .redirect(contextPath  + "/faces/OpenedAccountsProductTypeLevel.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```